# How to insert multiple rows using last id in mysql?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am trying to create row and then use its id to create dependent rows in another table.
To achieve this I want to use procedure, however there is problem with loop, which I do not understand. Any tip would be appreciated.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE CreateTask(
tname VARCHAR(256), 
temployees JSON(256)
)
BEGIN
DECLARE counter INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE tid INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE eid INT DEFAULT 0;

START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO tasks(name) VALUES(tname);

SET tid = LAST_INSERT_ID();
IF tid > 0 THEN
    
    WHILE counter <= JSON_LENGTH(temployees) DO
    SET counter <= counter + 1;
    SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(temployees,CONCAT('$[',counter,']')) INTO eid;
    INSERT INTO tasks_employees(id_task, id_employee) VALUES(tid, eid); 
    END WHILE;

    COMMIT;
 ELSE
ROLLBACK;
END IF;

END$$

DELIMITER ;

CREATE TABLE `tasks` (
`id_task` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(256) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `tasks_employees` (
`id_task` char(23) NOT NULL,
`id_employee` char(23) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `tasks`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_task`);

ALTER TABLE `tasks_employees`
ADD UNIQUE KEY `tasks_employee` (`id_task`,`id_employee`),
ADD KEY `id_task` (`id_task`),
ADD KEY `id_employee` (`id_employee`);

ALTER TABLE `tasks`
MODIFY `id_task` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Can you please share the table schema as well?

Comment: I have added simplified schema. Table tasks has also triggers but none for table tasks_employees.

Comment: Sorry for not asking this earlier, but can you please mention the proper error code (if you're facing any)? or Can you please elaborate "however there is problem with loop"? and explain what you expect and what you're getting?

Comment: Try [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=f1abdeef22935cb0e57ba5447fd62c7f).

Comment: MyISAM??  In a transaction??  Not!

Comment: I'm missing the problem -- there is only one `tid`; it is effectively outside the loop.

Comment: `tasks` does not have an `AUTO_INCREMENT`, so there is no `LAST_INSERT_ID()`.  (Maybe you oversimplified the code?)

Comment: table tasks has autoincrement: MODIFY `id_task` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

Comment: **wchiquito**, thank you for fiddle. It helped a lot. However task ids are chars and if in fiddle numbers are being replaced in array for chars, loop stops to work. I have tried combinations with apostrophes, but it did not helped. I made new feedle to show the problem. I would be grateful for advice. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=18aa7dedeff3ce84a5aa9fada63997e8

Comment: Sorry I meant employee id.

Comment: Check [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=53230546c6805be5c8d55b216f75cf58). Keep in mind what @RickJames said, `MyISAM` does not support transactions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final working procedure. Thank you **wchiquito**.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `CreateTask` (
`tname` VARCHAR(256),
`temployees` JSON
)
BEGIN
DECLARE `counter` INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE `tid` INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE `eid` CHAR(23) DEFAULT '';

START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO `tasks` (`name`) VALUES (`tname`);

SET `tid` = LAST_INSERT_ID();

IF `tid` > 0 THEN
WHILE `counter` < JSON_LENGTH(`temployees`) DO
  SELECT JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(`temployees`, CONCAT('$[', `counter` ,']'))) INTO `eid`;
  INSERT INTO `tasks_employees` (`id_task`, `id_employee`) VALUES (`tid`, `eid`);
  SET `counter` = `counter` + 1;
END WHILE;

COMMIT;
ELSE
ROLLBACK;
END IF;
END;
```